# Call a function and prevent the called function from performing a redirect in PHP

Tags: php, redirect

I'm calling a function which performs a redirect at the end. Can i prevent the function i called from performing a redirect somehow?

```
function a() {
    // here i would want to prevent the redirect. but i must call b always
    b();
    return 'a';
}

//function that i can't modify. It always redirects.
function b() {
    header("Location: http://google.com", true, 200 );
}

$return = a();

echo $return;
// expected output: 'a' not a redirect to google
```

If you ask why, i would not want to modify function `b()` as it's a library function.

Comment: can't you just add a `return` to exit a ?

Comment: Does `b()` only redirect? Couldn't you just wrap the call to `b()` in an if statement?

Comment: The OP says the function performs a redirect at the end, so I guess it's implicit there's more stuff in it.

Comment: several simple answers but due to OP rep, i suspect theirs missing info

Comment: Just don't redirect...

Comment: I'm not saying the answer must be difficult. if i call a(), it will call b() which will always redirect, so i will always end up on google. I don't want to end up on google :)

Comment: @Brad i do not control b().

Comment: edit a to not call b, or only conditionally call b

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti Well, if you can't modify your code then what is it that you expect us to suggest?  You could always clear out the header later, but why?

Comment: @Dagon i modified the question, i must call b()

Comment: Ok solved i finally found a way to override the library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you've called the library function, try using

```
header_remove("Location")
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header-remove.php

Hopefully that header wouldn't have sent yet...

Comment: Got a different solution, i've found a way to override the library :D

Comment: It's a filter in wordpress.

Comment: I should have written the whole question and i would have found the answer earlier if i did :D

Comment: I think it's still a useful PHP question. I didn't know about header_remove until now, so thanks for asking :)

Answer (score 0):

what about header_remove (after you set the header)?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header-remove.php